# Can't Display Price Data Using Ebay Finding Advanced API In React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ebay-api

I'm successfully querying data from eBay using the Finding Advanced API.  I'm mapping through the items to display on a page. I can display the title and image for the items queried.  However I'm having trouble when I try to pull down the price, which is nested in an array.

The data looks like this:

```
   {
itemId: [
"120901386991"
],
title: [
"1952 Topps Mickey Mantle Chase Card Box 18 packs 5 1950s or 1960's cards per box"
],
globalId: [
"EBAY-US"
],
subtitle: [
"3 BX LOT. 1 VINTAGE PK PER 25 BOXES* LOOK 4 1952 MANTLE"
],
primaryCategory: [
{
categoryId: [
"213"
],
categoryName: [
"Baseball Cards"
]
}
],
secondaryCategory: [
{
categoryId: [
"156521"
],
categoryName: [
"Vintage Non-Sport Cards"
]
}
],
galleryURL: [
"https://thumbs4.ebaystatic.com/m/m1mtMB65mAApWQ2EhJy4qWA/140.jpg"
],
viewItemURL: [
"https://rover.ebay.com/rover/1/711-53200-19255-0/1?ff3=2&toolid=10044&campid=5338164673&customid=watchbask&lgeo=1&vectorid=229466&item=120901386991"
],
paymentMethod: [
"PayPal"
],
autoPay: [
"true"
],
location: [
"USA"
],
country: [
"US"
],
shippingInfo: [
{
shippingServiceCost: [
{
@currencyId: "USD",
__value__: "0.0"
}
],
shippingType: [
"Free"
],
shipToLocations: [
"Worldwide"
],
expeditedShipping: [
"false"
],
oneDayShippingAvailable: [
"false"
],
handlingTime: [
"1"
]
}
],
sellingStatus: [
{
currentPrice: [
{
@currencyId: "USD",
__value__: "118.0"
}
],
convertedCurrentPrice: [
{
@currencyId: "USD",
__value__: "118.0"
}
],
sellingState: [
"Active"
],
timeLeft: [
"P13DT19H16M11S"
]
}
],
listingInfo: [
{
bestOfferEnabled: [
"false"
],
buyItNowAvailable: [
"false"
],
startTime: [
"2012-04-23T16:52:17.000Z"
],
endTime: [
"2019-10-23T16:52:17.000Z"
],
listingType: [
"FixedPrice"
],
gift: [
"false"
],
watchCount: [
"444"
]
}
],
returnsAccepted: [
"false"
],
condition: [
{
conditionId: [
"1000"
],
conditionDisplayName: [
"Brand New"
]
}
],
isMultiVariationListing: [
"false"
],
pictureURLLarge: [
"https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NTAwWDMxNA==/z/sT8AAOSw62VZv9qQ/$_1.JPG"
],
topRatedListing: [
"false"
]
},
```

I've passed down props using a 'card' notation which is the ebay Item. I can also see the props in google dev tools.

Thus while i can successfully display the title, using `{card.title}` in react

when i go to use `{card.sellingStatus.convertedCurrentPrice}` i get this error:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'convertedCurrentPrice' of undefined**

I've tried a few other variations but nothing seems to be working.

Note here is my 'Card' component where I am trying to display (this code shows the other alternative I am using for price.

```
  const Card = props => {
  const { card } = props;
  return (
    <div className="col-md-3">
      <div className="card">
        <div className="card-block">
          {/* <h5 className="card-title">{card.title}</h5> */}
          <div className="mx-auto" style={{ width: 200 }}>
            <img
              src={card.pictureURLLarge}
              style={{
                width: 190,
                height: 200
              }}
              className="img-responsive"
              alt="..."
            />
          </div>
          <div className="card-body">
            <h2>{card.sellingStatus.convertedCurrentPrice["__value__"]}</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Note also, here is my map function

```
 {card_list.map(item => (
                      <Card key={item.id} card={item} />
```

AM i missing something here?

Comment: Are you sure sellingStatus is an array? Here it looks an object.
https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/Samples/findItemsAdvanced_basic_out_json.txt

Comment: Here’s output i am getting from api  https://pastebin.com/mqCscKss

Comment: I cannot access pastebin, can you add to the question?

Comment: okay, i posted to start of my question

Comment: Almost everything there seem to be in an array, interesting api response.

Comment: Cant you access th converted price like this?
card.sellingStatus[0].convertedCurrentPrice[0]["__value__"]

Comment: It is reformating before and after value must be __

Comment: i'm trying this `{card.sellingStatus[0].convertedCurrentPrice[0]["__value__"]}` and still getting same undefined error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see sellingStatus is an array. so you will have to either map or get the value like this.

```
card.sellingStatus['convertedCurrentPrice]["__value__"]
```

or

```
card.sellingStatus[0].currentPrice[0]["__value__"];
```

since you do not need multiple `<h2>`

```
card.sellingStatus && card.sellingStatus[0].currentPrice[0]["__value__"];
```

So that it does not throw an error while the promise resolves.

Comment: thanks Udit, i'm trying like this `{card.sellingStatus["convertedCurrentPrice"]["__value__"]}` and still having the same issue

Comment: can you post a fiddle or at least one object from the api call?

Comment: sorry away from work for a while, does this help (this is sample output from ebay) https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/Samples/findItemsAdvanced_basic_out_json.txt#

Comment: by using the response from the above link, I am able to get to the data by using

response.item.map( card => ( <div> { card.sellingStatus.convertedCurrentPrice} </div>));

Comment: yes for some reason, the data that I'm pulling is returned in a slightly different format as I show at the beginning of my question, with the nested arrays.  I can post the full output a bit later

Comment: here's pastebin of output to show you what I'm talking about https://pastebin.com/mqCscKss

Comment: so i tried both of these-- i assume on the first one you meant to wrap the price in quotes, so i tried like this `{card.sellingStatus["convertedCurrentPrice"]["__value__"]}`  neither solution is working--still getting the same undefined error

Comment: Just put ‘card.sellingStatus && ‘ before the second one

Comment: you're a miracle worker!  it worked!  can you please explain why the heck this is working?

Comment: it happens with fetch when request is not completed and the view gets rendered. If component renders before the fetch completion it will always throw empty value and hence state will not show values from fetch.

Comment: @JohnRogerson what card.sellingStatus && is doing is its checking if value is there. And only if its there, it will show.

Comment: @JohnRogerson No problem. Please accept my solution if it helped.

Comment: udit, quick quick question.  on the above conditional statement, if i want to show a "0" if there is no value, how would i do that, i tried something like this (on another field) and just coming up blank `{item.listingInfo ? item.listingInfo[0].watchCount : "0"}`

Comment: Did you try with ‘ { item.listingInfo !== [] ? item.listingInfo[0].watchCount : “0” } ‘

Comment: actually i figured it out.  this did the trick `{item.listingInfo[0].watchCount ? item.listingInfo[0].watchCount : 0}` thanks!